# Selection rules for electronic transitions in dipole approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, perturbation-theory, hydrogen, dipole

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWo2b-i6UiE) which provides a clear, though simple, introduction to the argument. I think the main thing missing is a proof for:

- $\Delta \ell = \pm 1 $
- $\Delta m_\ell = 0, \pm 1$
- $\Delta m_s  = 0$ (which is not even mentioned)

which is presented as sort of a given.
I saw a bunch of sites. Some say it's due to Cleibsch-Gordan coefficients, others begin with the Quadratic Stark Shift... maybe it's all connected, but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mathematical and a physical way to look at it. From the physical point of view, photons carry angular momentum $\pm 1$. Thus, due to the conservation of the total angular momentum, the absorption/emission of a photon is possible only between the states whose total angular momentum differs by $1$. Since only one electron participate sin an absorption/emission event, flipping its spin could account for this, but this does not necessarily happen - hence the rule for the orbital angular momentum.

Mathematically, this follows from calculating the matrix element of the atom-photon interaction between the relevant atomic orbitals (i.e., the matrix element that enters the Fermi golden rule). In the *dipole approximation* this interaction is proprotional to $\mathbf{r}$, i.e. we calculate
$$
\int d\mathbf{r}\psi_{final}^*(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{r}\psi_{initial}(\mathbf{r})
$$
The transitions are possible only when this matrix element is not zero. This is where Cleibsch-Gordan coefficients or some other math may enter - depending on the specific situation one is dealing with.

**Remark:** [here is my short derivation of the dipole approximation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597994/selection-rules-in-the-harmonic-oscillator/598008#598008) (in somewhat different context)

Comment: "The transitions are possible only when this matrix element is zero"... Uhm, why?

Comment: Because this is the matrix element in the Fermi golden rule - it it is zero, then the transition rate is zero, i.e., no transitions.

Comment: Excuse me, you said before "transitions are possible" and now "no transitions".

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be non-zero.

Comment: Ok, one final question... if $\psi_{final}$ and $\psi_{initial}$ are two eigenstates relative to different eigenvalues, they should be orthogonal, so why isn't the matrix element _always_ zero? (After all, I'm sort of projecting a vector onto two orthogonal components ... that should give me zero no matter what)

Comment: Because you are computing perturbations, the dipole term shifts the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions and creates overlaps which are computed from the "free" or unperturbed part

Comment: @ric.san Note that there is also $\mathbf{r}$ in the integral - it is not the same integral that is zero according to the orthogonality relation.